# How to generate a unique random number in a specific format and check that it is not used?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to generate a random number in the format 105-##### and I need to check this generated number against the already created numbers before saving it to the database to make sure it doesn't exist.

Here is my code to generate the number itself:

```
$digits = 5;
$second_num = str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $digits)-1), $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order_gen = "105-".$second_num;
```

Now that I have this $order_gen number, what is the best way to loop through what I already have in the order_number database table to make sure there are no duplicates? I was thinking of using a while loop but not sure how to apply it.

Comment: Why use a random number generator if all you will do is make sure it is unique? Why not just do a one-up number? Then you don't have to check for randomness. Just find the largest one that currently exists, and start there? (If there is sufficient space after it for the pattern you desire)

Comment: I would vastly prefer that haha, but the client I am working with insists on a non-incremental solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your algorithm, there isn't a better way except to query the database for each ID you generate, until you find one that isn't taken.

Wrap the entire thing in a `do/while` statement, and define a method which queries the database by that random ID, returning true if the record exists, and false otherwise:

```
do {
  $digits = 5;
  $second_num = str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $digits)-1), $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $order_gen = "105-".$second_num;
} while (record_exists($order_gen);
```

Alternatively, generate randomly once, and then increment until you find a number that isn't taken:

```
$digits = 5;
$second_num = str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $digits)-1), $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order_gen = "105-".$second_num;

while (record_exists($order_gen) {
  $second_num += 1
  $second_num = str_pad($second_num, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $order_gen = "105-".$second_num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options that I can think of:

1. Generate an id and query to see if it is used. If used, generate another and repeat until you find one that is not used. This will probably be the slowest.
2. Have a table with all possible ids. Select a random row from that table, use that id and delete it so it won't be used again. This requires a table just for holding these ids though. Depending on your needs, this might not be possible.
3. In PHP, query all existing ids order by id. Loop over result and make an array of all ids. From there you can generate, if exists in array generate again like #1 or make an array of all possible ids, `array_diff($allIDS, $usedIDs)` to find ones not in use and array_rand to get a random one. This option uses more memory in php having to query out all existing ids.

All 3 methods will possibly suffer from race conditions where an id could be duplicated if two requests happened at the same time. #2 would probably be easiest to prevent race conditions. On the delete query, check the count of affected rows (PDOStatement::rowCount if using PDO) and if 0, assume someone else got it before you could use it and get another id.

Answer (score -1):

This can do the work

```
$rand = mt_rand(000123,999999); //prefix between 000123 to 999999
$id = "105".$rand;

$error = true;
while($error){
 $query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = '$id'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($count!=0){
   $error = true;
   $rand = mt_rand(000123,999999);
   $id = "105".$rand;    
  }else{
   $error = false;
  }
}
```